# Nginx reverse proxy - which headers are used to pass the domain

Tags: http, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am playing around with Nginx reverse proxy.

I have configured multiple subdomains, on which nginx responds correctly.

Example:

```html
server {
    server_name wiki.some.domain;
    listen 80 ;
    ...
}

server {
    server_name card.some.domain;
    listen 80 ;
    ...
}
```

I ask myself - which headers are used, to tell nginx, from which domain the traffic is coming?

Is the header defined by the HTTP protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx basically uses the `Host` header to match the correct `server_name`.

> In this configuration nginx tests only the request’s header field “Host” to determine which server the request should be routed to. If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default server for this port.

Reference: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html